# Is there a way to change the register of Super Mario Bros (NES) level 1 world 1 to start in a specific position?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, nes

I've been using the gym-super-mario-bros library (https://github.com/Kautenja/gym-super-mario-bros) and I was trying to change the registers' values in order to set the position of Mario to a specific position inside level 1 in world 1.

I tried to check the RAM information map  (https://datacrystal.romhacking.net/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros.:RAM_map), but if I change the page information in 0x6d and the position inside the page (0x86), Mario always move to 0 position at the very beginning of the game. In the library code I modified the values inside the `_x_position` function in **smb_env.py**.

Comment: I would almost bet it's more than just a register. From what little I understand, that game runs on a paging system, so you'd need to set the correct page somewhere in RAM, then set Mario's X position, and then make sure the current blocks and objects are loaded for whichever page you've asked Mario to start on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the NESEnv class there are functions for saving the current state of the emulator and another for restoring it.
These are named `_backup` and `_restore`, respectively.
You can call these like this:

```
env = gym_super_mario_bros.make(version)
env.unwrapped._backup()
env.unwrapped._restore()
```